# Infinite Product - Seems to telescope

Tags: infinite-product

Evaluate

$$\left(1 + \frac{2}{3+1}\right)\left(1 + \frac{2}{3^2 + 1}\right)\left(1 + \frac{2}{3^3 + 1}\right)\cdots$$

It looks like this product telescopes: the denominators cancel out (except the last one) and the numerators all become 3.

What would my answer be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we have the following identity (which affirms that the product telescopes):
$$\left (1+\frac{2}{3^n+1}\right)=3\cdot\frac{3^{n-1}+1}{3^n+1}=\frac{1+3^{-(n-1)}}{1+3^{-n}}$$

(as denoted in the comment by Thomas Andrews)and as a result:
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \left (1+\frac{2}{3^k+1}\right)=\frac{2\cdot 3^n}{3^n+1}=\frac{2}{1+3^{-n}}$$

Comment: If you divide the numerator and denominator by $3^{n}$ you get an even more obvious telescope: $$\frac{1+3^{-(n-1)}}{1+3^{-n}}$$ without that extraneous $3$. And the partial product is: $$\frac{1+3^{0}}{1+3^{-n}}$$

Comment: How did you get the 2 * 3^n / 3^n + 1 part?

Comment: $$\prod_{i=1}^n a\frac{f(i-1)}{f(i)}=a^n\frac{f(0)}{f(n)} $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The general form of a factor is
$$
1+\frac{2}{3^n+1}=\frac{3^n+3}{3^n+1}=\frac{3\cdot(3^{n-1}+1)}{3^n+1}
$$
Now, can you find the general form of a partial product?